# Ignore comma when it appears between quotation marks in pyspark RDD

Tags: regex, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have loaded a csv file into RDD which looks like this:

```
['"3331/587","Sub,Metro","1235","1000"',
'"1234/232","City","8479","2000"',
'"5987/215","Sub,Metro","1111","Unknown"',
'"8794/215","Sub,Metro","1112","1000"',
'"1254/951","City","6598","XXXX"',
'"1584/951","City","1548","Unknown"',
'"1833/331","Sub,Metro","1009","2000"',
'"2213/987","City","1197", ']
```

What I finally want to achieve is

```
[["3331/587","Sub,Metro","1235","1000"],
["1234/232","City","8479","2000"],
["5987/215","Sub,Metro","1111","Unknown"],
["8794/215","Sub,Metro","1112","1000"],
["1254/951","City","6598","XXXX"],
["1584/951","City","1548","Unknown"],
["1833/331","Sub,Metro","1009","2000"],
["2213/987","City","1197", ]]
```

If I use this code:

```
sc.textFile(file).map(lambda l: l.replace(r'"', '').split(','))
```

It also separates by comma inside the value ("Sub,Metro")

How can I automatically ignore all comma between "" when splitting by comma?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example with regular expression.

```
import re

rdd = sc.parallelize(['"3331/587","Sub,Metro","1235","1000"',
'"1234/232","City","8479","2000"',
'"5987/215","Sub,Metro","1111","Unknown"',
'"8794/215","Sub,Metro","1112","1000"',
'"1254/951","City","6598","XXXX"',
'"1584/951","City","1548","Unknown"',
'"1833/331","Sub,Metro","1009","2000"',
'"2213/987","City","1197", '])

rdd.map(lambda l: re.split(r'[^A-z],[^A-z]', re.sub(r'(^["])|(["]$)','', l))).collect()

[['3331/587', 'Sub,Metro', '1235', '1000'],
 ['1234/232', 'City', '8479', '2000'],
 ['5987/215', 'Sub,Metro', '1111', 'Unknown'],
 ['8794/215', 'Sub,Metro', '1112', '1000'],
 ['1254/951', 'City', '6598', 'XXXX'],
 ['1584/951', 'City', '1548', 'Unknown'],
 ['1833/331', 'Sub,Metro', '1009', '2000'],
 ['2213/987', 'City', '1197', '']]
```